# Spark IN/EXISTS predicate in SELECT statement

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Spark SQL test query:

```scala
Seq("france").toDF.createOrReplaceTempView("countries")
```

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN country = 'italy' THEN 'Italy' 
    ELSE ( CASE WHEN country IN (FROM countries) THEN upperCase(country) ELSE country END ) 
    END AS country FROM users
```

which throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
    IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in a Filter
```

the following part of the query `CASE WHEN country IN (FROM countries)` is the reason for that.

Is there any workaround in Spark SQL exists in order to emulate `country IN (FROM countries)` in the select conditions? I interested in pure SQL implementation and not in the implementation via API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the correct SQL query:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._

Seq("france").toDF("country").createOrReplaceTempView("countries")
Seq(("user1", "france"), ("user2", "italy"), ("user2", "usa"))
  .toDF("user", "country").createOrReplaceTempView("users")

val query =
  s"""
     |SELECT
     |  CASE
     |    WHEN u.country = 'italy' THEN 'Italy'
     |    ELSE (
     |      CASE
     |        WHEN u.country = c.country THEN upper(u.country)
     |        ELSE u.country
     |      END
     |    ) END AS country
     |FROM users u
     |LEFT JOIN countries c
     |  ON u.country = c.country
  """.stripMargin
sparkSession.sql(query).show()
```

Result:

```
+-------+
|country|
+-------+
| FRANCE|
|  Italy|
|    usa|
+-------+
```

The reason behind the scene you can use `IN/EXISTS` sql operators only in predicates is: logic in projections (`CASE-WHEN` in our case) **evaluated for each row** in data set returned from selection.
With this in mind, it's not the best idea to run equivalent of `CASE WHEN country IN (SELECT * FROM countries)` for each row from `users` table. So, SQL prevents this on language level (sql parser engine).

Comment: Is there any way to operate on each row? It's exactly what I am trying to do with a decision table whose rules span multiple rows and contain arrays of values. If Column A has the rules, then I use case when to check column B for 'in' / 'not in'. Case when column B = 'in', then fieldToMap in (exploded column A), case when column B = 'not in' then fieldToMap not in (exploded column A). I nest this inside a sum that counts the matches, which determines the final value for that row. All the SQL works outside the case when block, but I don't know how to go line by line without case when.

Comment: Could you bring an example please? Case-when operates exactly on row level. Alternative approach might be to use declarative dataframe API and/or custom UDF

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use

> withColumn()

and

> when()

function (from [spark.sql.functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)):

```
val users = Seq(("1", "france"), ("2", "Italy"), ("3", "italy")).toDF("userId", "country")
val countriesList = Seq("france", "italy", "germany").toList

val result = users.withColumn("country", when(col("country") === "italy", "Italy")
  .when(col("country") isin(countriesList:_*), upper(col("country"))).otherwise(col("country")))

result.show()
```

Result:

```
+------+-------+
|userId|country|
+------+-------+
|     1| FRANCE|
|     2|  Italy|
|     3|  Italy|
+------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right now I'm mostly interested in pure SQL implementation.